# Mutation attempt of immutable types in for loop doesn't raise SyntaxError?

Tags: python, list

Consider the following code.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
for i in a: 
    i *= 2

a
#[1, 2, 3]
```

As I understand it, inplace operators like `*=` attempt to mutate the element via  `__iadd()__`. Assuming `type(i) == <class 'int'>` as it goes through the loop, shouldn't the for loop in this example then raise a SyntaxError? (for trying to mutate immutable integers from the list?)

Why doesn't it neither change the list elements nor raise an error?

Comment: @jpp This is not a duplicate to the question you marked. This question is simply about variables of scalar types always being mutable, so modifying a scalar variable anywhere is never going to cause a syntax error, even though in the OP's case the changes made to the scalar variable is not going to be reflected in the original list.

Comment: Why `SyntaxError`? The syntax is fine. But `i *= 2` does `i = i.__imul__(2)` which rebinds the local name `i` to the resulting `int` instead of mutating the original list item.

Comment: @blhsing, Please read the answers to the duplicate.

Comment: @jpp I stand corrected. Thanks.

Comment: For a good intro to mutability I suggest https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html